# Вирутальное окружение в PyCharm работает некорректно(не та версия Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, venv, python-3.11

Всем привет. Решил уставить Python 3.11. Когда создаю виртуальное окружение все хорошо, версия стоит 3.11
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в Pycharm скрипт запускается все равно запускается со старой версией почему-то. Хотя если посмотреть на виртуальное окружение, то там тоже указан 3.11[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при запуске скрипта версия 3.10.4

```
import sys
print(sys.version)

C:\Users\dayyy\Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\dayyy\Python\main\main.py 

3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Пересоздавать в самом PyCharm пробовал, перезапускал и все такое
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если решать прям в лоб - то это через терминал, находясь  в виртуальном окружении, установить нужную версию через pip:

```
pip install --upgrade python==3.11
```

А вообще, судя по 3 блоку кода, у тебя пейчарм вообще использует не то окружение, которое ты выбрал в настройках, посмотри на пути повнимательнее. Попробуй создать отдельную папку main в которой будут venv и main, и попробуй выбрать настройки при создании как на изображении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внимательно посмотри на пути.

Comment: спасибо, я про этот пункт меню вообще забыл